# How to convert 2 columns into target indicies

Tags: python, pandas

I have a mock pandas dataframe consisting of 4 columns (x, y, color, marker). I want to combine the color, marker columns into one column which has a number corresponding to every different color marker pair. I have tried searching online but couldn't find a problem like this one. I have tried bringing in the get_dummies pandas call but I didn't want the numbers in one hot encoding and wanted a faster method then converting to one hot encoding then converting in into my target indices.

For example:

```
        Color    Marker
    0     r        ^
    1     r        *
    2     r        ^ 
    3     b        *
```

Would turn into:

```
      Combined
    0     1
    1     2
    2     1
    3     3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please include some sample input, expected output & the code snippet of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to work:

```
import pandas as pd
 
dd = {
'Color': ['r','r','r','b'],
'Marker': ['^','*','^','*']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dd)

# create lookup table
dflkup = df[['Color','Marker']];
dflkup = dflkup.drop_duplicates()  # distinct combinations

dflkup.insert(0, 'Combined', range(1, len(dflkup)+1)) # number each combination

# join original data
dffull = pd.merge(df, dflkup, on=['Color','Marker'], how='outer') 

print(dffull.to_string(index=False))
```

Output

```
Color Marker  Combined
    r      ^         1
    r      ^         1
    r      *         2
    b      *         3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to label encode a combination of 2 columns in your dataset. A quick and reliable way for this is to use the sklearn Labelencoder after combining the 2 columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Color': ['r','r','r','b'],
'Marker': ['^','*','^','*']
})


from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
lb = LabelEncoder()      #Instantiate the label encoder 

df['combined'] = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)  #Concatenate the 2 cols (it doesnt work on iteratables)
df['combined'] = lb.fit_transform(df['combined']) #fit and transform the column
df
```

```
  Color Marker  combined
0     r      ^         2
1     r      *         1
2     r      ^         2
3     b      *         0
```

The good part of this method is that you can maintain the object and metadata as part of the object defined and get some useful utility functions as well.

```
list(enumerate(lb.classes_))

[(0, 'b*'), (1, 'r*'), (2, 'r^')]
```

```
[tuple(i) for i in lb.inverse_transform([0, 2, 1])]

[('b', '*'), ('r', '^'), ('r', '*')]
```